# How to set the size/location of a central widget in QT

Tags: c++, qt, resize, widget

I have a central widget with several doc widgets surrounding it. When i hide it, the docs resizes to fill the space however, when i show the central widget back, it is show with its default size. I want to be able to resize and position it as it was before being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Before hiding do something like this:

```
QSize storedSize = mainwindow->getCentralWidget->size();
```

(assuming `mainwindow` is a `* QMainWindow` containing the central widget you are talking about)

When you want to resize it back to the old size:

```
mainwindow->getCentralWidget->resize(storedSize);
```

Comment: and for position do the same with QPoint, pos() and move().